# Laravel const validation

Tags: laravel, validation, constants

I currently have validation set within my controller for a column which contains consts

**Controller**

```
protected $validation = [
  'state' =>
     'in:' . FilmState::ACTIVE . ',' . FilmState::INACTIVE
];
```

**const file**

```
class FilmState
{
    public const ACTIVE = 'active';
    public const INACTIVE = 'inactive';
}
```

Is there a way i can list the const in one array and how would i then pass this into the validation within my validation array in the controller?

**Const Attempt**

```
public const STATES = [
    'active',
    'inactive'
];
```

**Controller validation attempt**

```
 protected $validation = [
  'state' =>
     'in:' . FilmState::STATES
];
```

i believe the const array is correct but im unsure how to add this array into the validation would my attempt above work?

Answer (score 0):

You should use in_array: instead of in: while trying to validate through array values. Or you can again use in: with implode(“,”,$array)

Comment: okay, so if i wanted to set a default value of that array in my migration e.g       $table->string('state')->default(FilmState::STATES['active']); this wouldnt work would it?

Comment: İn your case you can use FilmState::STATES

Comment: how would that know that available was the default from the array?

Comment: Your array is FilmState::STATES. So in your attempt just replace FilmState::STATES with implode(“,”, FilmState::STATES)